# How to customize word template on c# for docs generate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, docx, template-engine, openxml-sdk

I have a word template with .docx format,
my question:

1. Can I get a list of tag names from the rich text content control
   that I have declared in the template like inside table and other else? and how?
   [(this is the example of template)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6Lfb.png)
2. Can I call a parameter from the return response database using a
   string? and how to retrieve deeper level data like this? (example are below)

```
{
    "id": "293",
    "user": "315",
    "userNavigation": {
      "id": "314",
      "name": "insomnia"
    },
    "department": [
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Tech"
      },
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Bio"
      },
     ],
}
```

I've used two libraries

1. OpenXml
2. TemplateEngine.Docx: https://bitbucket.org/unit6ru/templateengine/src/master/
   I do not use third party services because they are not paid.

Comment: For the first question, do you mean you want to get the tags from the word template? If that is the case, I suggest you could ask for the [TemplateEngine.Docx forum](https://github.com/UNIT6-open/TemplateEngine.Docx/issues). Because from the [TemplateEngine document](https://bitbucket.org/unit6ru/templateengine/src/master/), I didn't find the related description about this feature.

Comment: About the second question, it seems that you want to deserialize the json string to an object, if that is the case, try to use the [JsonSerializer.Deserialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1) method.

Comment: @ZhiLv thank you for your answer.

if like then maybe I stop to find a solution related to this.